# How can I install conda packages on Linux if they were originally installed on Windows?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda

I have conda installed locally on my Windows PC and also installed remotely on a Linux server. I already have conda packages installed locally on my Windows PC, and I want to install the same packages on the Linux server. I have already tried the following steps:

1. Create a `requirements.txt` file containing the currently installed packages and their versions using the Anaconda Prompt on my Windows PC using the command `conda list -e > requirements.txt`.
2. Transfer this `requirements.txt` file to my Linux server.
3. Install these packages in my `conda` `base` environment using the command `conda install --yes --file requirements.txt`.

However, I get the following error message on my Linux server when I try to complete step 3:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ca-certificates==2020.12.8=haa95532_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core==5.3.0=7
  - audioread==2.1.8=pypi_0
  - pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0=py38_1000
  - notebook==6.1.5=py38haa95532_0
  - librosa==0.8.0=pypi_0
  - numpy-base==1.19.2=py38ha3acd2a_0
  - psutil==5.7.2=py38he774522_0
  - numpy==1.19.2=py38hadc3359_0
  - regex==2020.11.13=py38h2bbff1b_0
  - spyder-kernels==1.10.0=py38haa95532_0
  - appdirs==1.4.4=pypi_0
  - ujson==4.0.1=py38ha925a31_0
  - setuptools==51.0.0=py38haa95532_2
  - sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.6=pypi_0
  - pywinpty==0.5.7=py38_0
  - m2w64-gmp==6.1.0=2
  - pyyaml==5.3.1=py38he774522_1
  - bzip2==1.0.8=he774522_0
  - sounddevice==0.4.1=pypi_0
  - certifi==2020.12.5=py38haa95532_0
  - gpytorch==1.3.0=pypi_0
  - winpty==0.4.3=4
  - pyzmq==20.0.0=py38hd77b12b_1
  - pytorch==1.7.1=py3.8_cpu_0
  - lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3=py38h2bbff1b_2
  - zeromq==4.3.3=ha925a31_3
  - ipython==7.19.0=py38hd4e2768_0
  - mkl_fft==1.2.0=py38h45dec08_0
  - conda-package-handling==1.7.2=py38h76e460a_0
  - vc==14.2=h21ff451_1
  - cpuonly==1.0=0
  - pip==20.3.1=py38haa95532_0
  - tornado==6.1=py38h2bbff1b_0
  - libarchive==3.4.2=h5e25573_0
  - msys2-conda-epoch==20160418=1
  - pandocfilters==1.4.3=py38haa95532_1
  - scikit-learn==0.23.2=pypi_0
  - torchaudio==0.7.2=py38
  - soundfile==0.10.3.post1=pypi_0
  - gsl==2.4=hfa6e2cd_4
  - kiwisolver==1.3.0=py38hd77b12b_0
  - argon2-cffi==20.1.0=py38he774522_1
  - dataclasses==0.6=pypi_0
  - libtiff==4.1.0=h56a325e_1
  - torchvision==0.8.2=py38_cpu
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git==5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - numba==0.51.2=pypi_0
  - pooch==1.2.0=pypi_0
  - cvxopt==1.2.0=py38hdc3235a_0
  - tabulate==0.8.7=pypi_0
  - pillow==8.0.1=py38h4fa10fc_0
  - libpng==1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
  - libiconv==1.15=h1df5818_7
  - rtree==0.9.4=py38h21ff451_1
  - qt==5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
  - ruamel_yaml==0.15.87=py38he774522_1
  - libsodium==1.0.18=h62dcd97_0
  - yaml==0.2.5=he774522_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libs==5.3.0=7
  - libspatialindex==1.9.3=h33f27b4_0
  - jedi==0.17.2=py38haa95532_1
  - tk==8.6.10=he774522_0
  - six==1.15.0=py38haa95532_0
  - python-crfsuite==0.9.7=pypi_0
  - spyder==4.2.0=py38haa95532_0
  - cffi==1.14.4=py38hcd4344a_0
  - xz==5.2.5=h62dcd97_0
  - console_shortcut==0.1.1=4
  - sqlite==3.33.0=h2a8f88b_0
  - pycosat==0.6.3=py38h2bbff1b_0
  - pyrsistent==0.17.3=py38he774522_0
  - markupsafe==1.1.1=py38he774522_0
  - bcrypt==3.2.0=py38he774522_0
  - libuv==1.40.0=he774522_0
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py38h2bbff1b_1003
  - mistune==0.8.4=py38he774522_1000
  - wrapt==1.11.2=py38he774522_0
  - powershell_shortcut==0.0.1=3
  - mkl-service==2.3.0=py38h196d8e1_0
  - pysocks==1.7.1=py38haa95532_0
  - typeguard==2.10.0=pypi_0
  - jpeg==9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - libxml2==2.9.10=hb89e7f3_3
  - freetype==2.10.4=hd328e21_0
  - python==3.8.5=h5fd99cc_1
  - liblief==0.10.1=ha925a31_0
  - sip==4.19.13=py38ha925a31_0
  - scipy==1.5.4=pypi_0
  - pywin32==227=py38he774522_1
  - nltk==3.5=pypi_0
  - py-lief==0.10.1=py38ha925a31_0
  - threadpoolctl==2.1.0=pypi_0
  - zlib==1.2.11=h62dcd97_4
  - cudatoolkit==10.2.89=h74a9793_1
  - zstd==1.4.5=h04227a9_0
  - mkl_random==1.1.1=py38h47e9c7a_0
  - glpk==4.65=hdc00fd2_2
  - ninja==1.10.2=py38h6d14046_0
  - joblib==0.17.0=pypi_0
  - typed-ast==1.4.1=py38he774522_0
  - pandas==1.1.3=py38ha925a31_0
  - llvmlite==0.34.0=pypi_0
  - resampy==0.2.2=pypi_0
  - pynacl==1.4.0=py38h62dcd97_1
  - vs2015_runtime==14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - icu==58.2=ha925a31_3
  - matplotlib-base==3.3.2=py38hba9282a_0
  - menuinst==1.4.16=py38he774522_1
  - pyqt==5.9.2=py38ha925a31_4
  - cryptography==3.3.1=py38hcd4344a_0
  - jupyter_core==4.7.0=py38haa95532_0
  - ax-platform==0.1.19=pypi_0
  - botorch==0.3.3=pypi_0
  - win_inet_pton==1.1.0=py38haa95532_0
  - pkginfo==1.6.1=py38haa95532_0
  - openssl==1.1.1i=h2bbff1b_0
  - wincertstore==0.2=py38_0
  - matplotlib==3.3.2=pypi_0
  - lz4-c==1.9.2=hf4a77e7_3
  - pandoc==2.11=h9490d1a_0
  - conda==4.9.2=py38haa95532_0
  - ad3==2.3.dev0=pypi_0
  - retrying==1.3.3=pypi_0
  - plotly==4.14.1=pypi_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran==5.3.0=6
  - watchdog==0.10.4=py38haa95532_0
  - chardet==3.0.4=py38haa95532_1003

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I am aware that the problem is that I am not looking in the correct `conda` channels, as the error message suggests, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation has some additional steps to have environment working cross-platform. [Here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms) is the link to that.

However, **if you are not using packages that are only available in anaconda channels**, you can do the following.

1. Have pip on both your conda environment (windows and linux server)
2. Make requirements.txt file using `pip freeze` instead of conda's one. From the windows machine

   $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
3. Install the packages in linux server normally with pip.

   $ pip install -r requirements.txt

I am not saying that it is the best option. But this way usually is easier can support other environment management packages like pyenv.